# How Can I View All Databases on a PostGIS server in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, database, pgadmin-3, connection

When I add a new PostGIS database connection to QGIS the dialog asks for the database name.

At times I want to add a database and can't remember the exact name or I want to add a database from a different server and I'm not sure what databases are available.

Is there a way to list all databases on a server within QGIS? I know I could look this information up in pgAdmin but I'd prefer to keep it within QGIS.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in _Add PostGIS Layers..._, but you can go to DB Manager, connect to a known db and run the following query `SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;`. It will list all the databases on the server. But I guess your question is more about being able to see the databases in the Add Layers window.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't an option directly available in QGIS.

According to [Displaying PostGIS geometries using QGIS](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiQGIS)

> The workflow is always identical. The first time, you have to define a connection to PostGIS database ((default values are : host:localhost , port:5432 , Database:postgres)). Then you will load a PostGIS table containing a geometry column as a new QGIS layer. Then this layer can be edited, and you have access to all the other columns (if the type is known by QGIS, else cast to ::text), for example to use it as a color categories, or as proportion field, etc.

QGIS documentation [Module: Using Spatial Databases in QGIS¶](https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/databases/index.html) doesn't refer to listing of database prior to connection as well. Just directly connect.